# Assigning variables using Numpy.arrary(, reading csvfile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to assign lat/lon to their corresponding columns in a csv file using Numpy.arrary(, however for some reason it is not reading the header. When I print the data frame the headers are present. The error im getting is raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Latitude'.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
latitude=np.array(data['Latitude'])
longitude=np.array(data['Longitude'])
```

[Headers for Latitude/Longitude shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur7Jf.png)

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
print(data.columns)
```

when I do the following this is the result:

```
Index(['Latitude,Longitude'], dtype='object')
```

here is what the csv file looks like:

```
Latitude,Longitude
-37.7,146.3667
-38.4583,144.0883
-37.1916,145.7116
-37.2833,142.95
-37.2769,142.9786
-38.0333,145.1
```

Comment: it's because your csv file doesn't contain a column named 'Latitude'. check the spelling

Comment: It has Latitude at the top of the csv file, spelt correctly.

Comment: The error says that the column name 'Latitude' is not found in your DataFrame. So, check the column names in your code exactly match the column names in your CSV as they are case-sensitive, you need to ensure it is correct.Try printing the column names to verify they match your code. `print(data.columns)` and also try removing leading/trailing spaces from column names, if any. `data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()`. Then try whatever you want to do.

Comment: @BeulahEvanjalin did the following still same error

Comment: Can you provide a sample (first 5 rows) of your csv file? Looking at the output of `data.columns` it seems that you only have one column called `Latitude,Longitude`...

Comment: `data=pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimeter=',')` do this to read the csv. and then do `print(data.columns)` to check if you have those two columns correctly

Comment: Can you provide a link to your data to check the unicode representation of the comma, please?

Answer (score 0):

You have only one columns named `'Latitude,Longitude'`:

```
Index(['Latitude,Longitude'], dtype='object')
```

And what you expect is:

```
Index(['Latitude', 'Longitude'], dtype='object')
```

So the separator of your data is not the comma (`U+002C`).
There are some similar [representation of comma](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002C) with different codes.
You can check it with:

```
for col in data.columns:
    print(col.encode('raw_unicode_escape'))
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

content = '''\
Latitude﹐Longitude
-37.7﹐146.3667
-38.4583﹐144.0883'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), sep=',')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Latitude﹐Longitude
0     -37.7﹐146.3667
1  -38.4583﹐144.0883

>>> df.columns
Index(['Latitude﹐Longitude'], dtype='object')

>>> for col in df.columns: print(col.encode('raw_unicode_escape'))
b'Latitude\\ufe50Longitude'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it appears that my csv file is one column even though I have commas. How could I fix this ?

Comment: Did you try to specify the `sep` parameter explicitly? `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')`? (try to copy/paste the character from the csv). What is the output of `import csv; print(list(csv.DictReader(open('data.csv'), delimiter=',')))`?

Comment: @SUPERREDPANDA. Does it solve your problem?